# Charset issue in RPG program runtime on iSeries db2 store procedure call

Tags: character-encoding, db2, odbc, rpgle, rpg

I have a db2 stored procedure like below. This proc is calling a CL to invoke an RPG program.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE bsm4obj/TXCL4055            
(                                            
INOUT POCNO CHAR (10),                       
INOUT POCRN DEC ( 2 , 0 ),                   
INOUT PSPNO CHAR (10),                       
INOUT PMTAD CHAR (1),                        
INOUT PYREX CHAR (1),                        
INOUT PMTYR CHAR (1),                        
INOUT PKMLK CHAR (10),                       
INOUT HATVR CHAR (1)                         
)                                            
LANGUAGE CL NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL EXTERNAL
NAME bsm4obj/txCL4055 PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL
```

I call this proc from the server. (ODBC language ID Turkish);

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("{CALL BSM4OBJ.TXCL4055(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}", as400con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

When executing the RPG program (in step like below) variable 'ŞŞ' is not recognizing by compiler like it is but '@@'.

> TSDEPR    IFEQ 'ŞŞ'
>
> //Reading like TSDEPR IFEQ '@@'

The program is executing perfectly in QPADEV session on As400 but on SQL call does not behave like this.

I replaced turkish static chars with equivalent char for temporary in RPG.
But i want to find exact solution.
I will be very pleased if you suggest

Comment: What is your system CCSID? What CCSID is the ODBC job `QZDASOINIT` running with? What CCSID is the interactive `QPADEV` job using? What CCSID was the program compiled with?

Comment: We could be looking at variables that didn't pass correctly here. 
Consider making your procedures with varchar & integer inout. Then have the procedure put the variables into the correct size for calling your CL programs and such.  You may be pleasantly surprised how easy they are to call via odbc and such.    Varchar and integer can be passed as constants from the calling procedure.

Answer (score 1):

By default, RPG doesn't always handle character literals correctly. It saves the hex value of the literal in the compile-time CCSID, but it interprets the hex value in the job CCSID.

Starting in 7.2, you can code H spec keyword CCSID(*EXACT), and that will cause RPG to remember the true CCSID of character literals.

Another workaround is to code the literal with %UCS2.

```
if TSDEPR = %ucs2('ŞŞ');
```